# Highcharts stacked bar logic is the opposite of what I need

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have an issue with a chart I need to do.
I have a blog with topics, and articles on each topic that can be in status "draft" "to be validated" or "published".

I want to display a chart which shows the repartition for each topic (not pies because I would need one pie by topic and I have many of them).

So I would like the render to be like this:
[image]

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Stacked bar chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Topic 1', 'Topic 2', 'Topic 3', 'Topic 4', 'Topic 5']
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Total fruit consumption'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        reversed: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal'
        }
    },
    series: [ {
        name: 'Published',
        color: '#2ecc71',
        data: [13, 14, 14, 12, 15]
    },{
        name: 'To be validated',
        color: '#e67e22',
        data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
    }, {
        name: 'Draft',
        color: '#f1c40f',
        data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
    }]
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/04mxw2h1/4/

But the logic of highcharts is the complete opposite of what I want to show, my series is not "draft" or "published" but for me, it should be "Topic 1", "Topic 2" etc. I could make it work but it seems wrong.

And my second problem is because I want to drill down, clicking on a Topic will show me sub-topics of the clicked topic. The problem is the concept of [highcharts drilldown](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/drilldown), it is on the series, so in my case, I could configure drill down for "draft" or "published" but I need to configure the drill down to be on the categories (topics). In other words, if the user clicks on any of the statuses of the topic 2, it should show values of subtopics for topic 2...

Some SO answers use `chart.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown` but it seems unofficial and it seems to be for asynchronous loading (eg: pulling data from backend after the drill down event) but I have all of my data already in my page so it does not seems to be the right solution.

Should I use this heavy solution of constructing series on the click event or can I use some options to invert series and categories in a stacked bar?

Comment: You could do it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/04mxw2h1/15/ That would allow you to easily make drilldown series, prepared. The obvious drawback, is that you will need to add colors, names and x coordinates to all data points. (unless you always put them in the same order, then you could do this: http://jsfiddle.net/04mxw2h1/25/ where you still have to give a `x` and `y` but no colors per point)

Comment: Forgot about the xAxis labels, here they work dynamically: http://jsfiddle.net/04mxw2h1/30/

Comment: This is amazing ! :) Tanks you ! For the first chart it is way way simpler ! But I cannot manage to make the drill down work: http://jsfiddle.net/04mxw2h1/36/ I think the `load` function is not called on drill down/up

Comment: You sent my link ;) (version 36)

Comment: hi @iBadGamer check http://jsfiddle.net/635vLdwt/. I used drill down series multiple times, create separate id series for each stack

Comment: But I want alls stacks of "topic1" to drill down with the same 
appearance as the first view, if I click on any of the statuses of the topic 1 I must see "Topic1-Subtopic1 (draft/to be validated, published) and "Topic1-Subtopic2 (draft/to be validated, published) With your exemple I have only one serie. I want something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/4ysrv but with the same render as the first view of my chart

Comment: I want to do something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ynpcf44o/

Comment: Is that the desired result?: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tzjwkq8r/